# Parametric fit with TensorFlow (Sersic profile of surface brightness of a galaxy)

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, data-fitting, astronomy

I have to perform a fit of some mock data I created, with a TensorFlow model (Sersic profile: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sérsic_profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9rsic_profile)), to learn the real parameters.

I simulated the galaxy, so I have the mock data ready (coordinates of each point on the 2D grid and its surface brightness value):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from astropy import units as u # import the units module
from scipy.special import gamma, gammainc # import the gamma function

import tensorflow as tf # import tensorflow

import seaborn as sns
sns.set_theme(style='white')

# Create a class to model the galaxy
class SersicGalaxy(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, x_center, y_center, q, phi, n, I_e, R_e):
        "Function to initialize the galaxy parameters"
        self.x = x # x coordinates
        self.y = y # y coordinates
        self.xc = x_center # x coordinate of the center
        self.yc = y_center # y coordinate of the center
        self.q = q # axis ratio
        self.phi = phi # position angle
        self.n = n # Sersic index
        self.Ie = I_e # intensity at the effective radius
        self.Re = R_e # effective radius
        
    def change_coords(self):
        "Function to change coordinates (rotation and scaling), to align the reference frame with the semi-major axis of the galaxy and to scale the coordinates by the axis ratio"
        x_rot = (self.x - self.xc) * np.cos(self.phi) + (self.y - self.yc) * np.sin(self.phi) # x coordinates after rotation
        y_rot = (self.y - self.yc) * np.cos(self.phi) - (self.x - self.xc) * np.sin(self.phi) # y coordinates after rotation
        return x_rot * self.q, y_rot # return the rotated/scaled coordinates
            
    def radius(self):
        "Function to compute the distance from the center of the galaxy to a given point (x,y) in the plane of the sky (after rotation and scaling)"
        xp, yp = self.change_coords()
        return np.sqrt(xp**2 + yp**2) # return the radius    
        
    def b(self):
        "Function to compute the Sersic parameter b"
        return 2.0 * self.n - 1.0/3.0 + 4.0/(405.0*self.n) + 46.0/(25515.0*self.n**2) + 131.0/(1148175.0*self.n**3) - 2194697.0/(30690717750.0*self.n**4)
        
    def sersic_profile(self):
        "Function to compute the Sersic profile of the galaxy (at a given radius)"
        return self.Ie * np.exp(-self.b() * ((self.radius() / self.Re)**(1.0/self.n) - 1.0)) # return the Sersic profile

# Creating a grid of coordinates
size = 2000 # define the size of the grid

x, y = np.meshgrid(
    np.linspace(-size/2, size/2, size),
    np.linspace(-size/2, size/2, size)
    ) * u.arcsec # Create the grid of coordinates

x, y = x.astype(np.float32).value, y.astype(np.float32).value # Get the values of the coordinates

# Parameters of the galaxy
xc = (0.0 * u.arcsec).astype(np.float32).value # x coordinate of the center of the galaxy
yc = (0.0 * u.arcsec).astype(np.float32).value # y coordinate of the center of the galaxy
q = 0.5 # Axis ratio
phi = (np.pi/3.0 * u.rad).astype(np.float32).value # Position angle
n = 4.0 # Sersic index
Ie = (20 * u.Lsun * u.arcsec**(-2)).astype(np.float32).value # Effective surface brightness
Re = (30 * u.arcsec).astype(np.float32).value # Effective radius

# Create the galaxy object
galaxy = SersicGalaxy(x, y, xc, yc, q, phi, n, Ie, Re) # Create the galaxy object
r = galaxy.radius() # Get the radius of the galaxy
sb = galaxy.sersic_profile() # Get the surface brightness of the galaxy
sb += np.abs(np.random.normal(0.0, 0.1, size=(size, size)).astype(np.float32)) # Add some noise to the surface brightness profile to simulate the noise in the observations
```

Then I converted the data into Tensors, defined a model and compiled/fitted the model to the data (with poor results..).

```
x_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(x, dtype=tf.float32) # convert the x coordinates to a tensor
y_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype=tf.float32) # convert the y coordinates to a tensor
r_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(r, dtype=tf.float32) # convert the radius to a tensor
sb_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(sb, dtype=tf.float32) # convert the surface brightness to a tensor

# Set up a model to fit the surface brightness profile of the galaxy
class SersicModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.xc = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform(shape=[], minval=-size/3, maxval=size/3, dtype=tf.float32), name="x_center", trainable=True) # x coordinate of the center of the galaxy
        self.yc = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform(shape=[], minval=-size/3, maxval=size/3, dtype=tf.float32), name="y_center", trainable=True) # y coordinate of the center of the galaxy
        self.q = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform(shape=[], minval=0.1, maxval=1.0, dtype=tf.float32), name="axis_ratio", trainable=True) # axis ratio
        self.phi = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform(shape=[], minval=0.0, maxval=np.pi, dtype=tf.float32), name="position_angle", trainable=True) # position angle
        self.n = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform(shape=[], minval=0.5, maxval=8.0, dtype=tf.float32), name="sersic_index", trainable=True) # Sersic index
        self.Ie = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform(shape=[], minval=15.0, maxval=25.0, dtype=tf.float32), name="intensity_at_Re", trainable=True) # intensity at the effective radius
        self.Re = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform(shape=[], minval=1.0, maxval=50.0, dtype=tf.float32), name="effective_radius", trainable=True) # effective radius
    
    def call(self, xy):
        x, y = xy # get the coordinates
        x_rot = (x - self.xc) * tf.cos(self.phi) + (y - self.yc) * tf.sin(self.phi) # x coordinates after rotation
        y_rot = (y - self.yc) * tf.cos(self.phi) - (x - self.xc) * tf.sin(self.phi) # y coordinates after rotation
        xp = x_rot * self.q # x coordinates after rotation and scaling
        yp = y_rot # y coordinates after rotation and scaling
        r = tf.sqrt(xp**2 + yp**2) # radius
        b = 2.0 * self.n - 1.0/3.0 + 4.0/(405.0*self.n) + 46.0/(25515.0*self.n**2) + 131.0/(1148175.0*self.n**3) - 2194697.0/(30690717750.0*self.n**4) # Sersic parameter b
        sb = self.Ie * tf.exp(-b * ((r / self.Re)**(1.0/self.n) - 1.0)) # Sersic profile
        return tf.math.log(sb) # return the log10 of the Sersic profile
    
    
tf.random.set_seed(42) # set the seed for reproducibility
sb_model = SersicModel() # create the model

sb_preds = np.exp(sb_model.predict((x_tf, y_tf))) # get the predictions of the model

sb_model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.1), loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()) # compile the model
sb_model.fit((x_tf, y_tf), tf.math.log(sb_tf), epochs=5000, verbose=1) # fit the model
```

I am now fitting the log of the surface brightness to reduce the spread of the values (it should help to converge faster), but I have tried also to fit the real values with many tries.. is there someone who can help me with this task?

Comment: No one can help? Please, I'm really stuck.